# Scheduled Trigger stopped working after schedule changes

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have number of pipelines which are associated with a scheduled trigger which makes them run every morning around 4:30 AM UTC. Whenever any new pipeline is added to the ecosystem, we just associate this trigger with it and new pipeline starts to get triggered along with other pipelines and everything works fine.

Now, we had to make a trivial change in trigger i.e. change the start time and so we did modify the trigger using DF portal UI and published it. We were expecting pipelines to get triggered as usual on this updated time based on the trigger, however none of the pipeline got triggered. Any pointer what could have caused it? Were we expected to re-associate trigger with all pipelines again (manually) and re-publish each pipeline?

[Update 1]: did try with re-associating trigger again with each pipeline manually and published, still it does not seem to get triggered on specified schedule.

Here is how the scheduled trigger definition looks like

```
{
"name": "MasterTrigger",
"properties": {
    "runtimeState": "Started",
    "pipelines": [
        {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "Pipeline_A",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            }
        },
        {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "Pipeline_B",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            }
        },
        // Commented for brevity
    ],
    "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1,
            "startTime": "2018-11-17T04:30:00.000Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC",
            "schedule": {
                "minutes": [
                    30
                ],
                "hours": [
                    4
                ]
            }
        }
    }
} }
```

[Update 2]: Yesterday, deleted old trigger entirely and re-created trigger with DF UI with exact same schedule parameters and re-associated it with all the pipelines again and published each individually, however still no sign of pipelines getting triggered on mentioned scheduled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating a trigger with a different name and the same settings? I guess even if you delete the old trigger, the same name may still cause problem.

Comment: Yes, have created the trigger with new name but same error.

Comment: What do you mean the same error? Not triggered? Schedule trigger doesn’t support past time.

Comment: If you want to test whether a trigger works, you could set a small interval.

Comment: same error - I meant that the trigger is not firing at all. Tried already by setting small interval but that too did not work.

Comment: what is your data factory region?

Comment: Region - West Europe

Comment: I create a simple pipeline with just a wait activity in it and associated it with a schedule trigger which run every 2 minutes. It works fine for me. How many pipelines is associated with your trigger? Have you tried the simple scenario as mine? We need narrow down the root cause.

Comment: Or maybe you could contact azure support.

Comment: will try and create another set of pipelines and associate a new trigger to keep it simple and test it out, however guess for the root cause - will need to reach Azure support. Appreciate your assistance on this.